# Generic repository - IRepository<T> or IRepository

Tags: c#, linq, generics, repository

I have seen two different approaches for creating generic repositories. What are differences between those two approaches (pros and cons) ?
Please diregard difference in the methods because I am interested in difference between

```
 public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
```

and

```
 public interface IRepository : IDisposable
```

Is there any difference in functionality, flexibility, unit testing ... ? What will I get or lose ?
Is there any difference how they are registered in Dependency Injection frameworks ?

**Option 1**

```
 public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
 {
       T Get(object id);
       void Attach(T entity);
       IQueryable<T> GetAll();
       void Insert(T entity);
       void Delete(T entity);
       void SubmitChanges();
 }
```

**Option 2**

```
 public interface IRepository : IDisposable
    {
        IQueryable<T> GetAll<T>();
        void Delete<T>(T entity);
        void Add<T>(T entity);
        void SaveChanges();
        bool IsDisposed();
    }
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The biggest difference is that `IRepository<T>` is bound to a single type while an `IRepository` is potentially bound to multiple types.  Which one is appropriate is highly dependent upon your particular scenario.

Generally speaking I find `IRepository<T>` to be more useful.  At the time of use it's extremely clear what the contents of `IRepository<T>` are (`T`).  On the other hand it's not clear from a given `IRepository` what is contained inside of it.

In cases where I have to store multiple types of objects, I usually create a map of `IRepository<T>` instances.  For instance: `Dictionary<T,IRepository<T>>`.

Comment: When my entities have very different methods I do not recommend implementing IRepository<T> for every entity because every entity will then have a empty implementation of a method which it might not use at all.

Do IRepository<T> only if your entities have much common methods else your Repository classes will end up containing empty methods.

Comment: I don't think an empty method is as dangerous as a giant, world ending solar flair.