# Windsor Ioc avoid call resolve all the time

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

Guys I need your help I am using Castle Project Windsor IoC container in my C# Winforms application. I have services classes which has DI by constructor passing in implementing Repositories. I used Windsor to register them all Component.Register(...etc but everytime I use my service class I am calling resolve. for example:
 
`var employeeService = container.Resolve....etc`
 is there any other way not having to call resolve all the time?
in ASP.NET you can just register them all then set the Controller factory:
 `ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new WindsorIoCFactory());`
with this I can just use my controllers(using services) directly without calling resolve. how do you do this in winforms?

Comment: I think this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4840907/1346943) should help you out

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) approach.

In short, you should use Resolve only once at the App-StartUp basically resolving the MainView and through that you should be able to obtain all views(most likely through a [TypedFactory](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories.ashx?HL=typedfactory)) and their dependencies with no explicit Resolve call.

Service locator approach, as per comment link, is a deprecable anti-pattern specially when Composition Root can be used instead.

On the windsor wiki you'll find a sample based on a [Silverlight app](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Silvertlight_Sample_App_Customer_contact_manager.ashx), very close to a Winform scenario.

Comment: Thanks Cristiano! will check Composition Root

Comment: Hi Cristiano.. if I have many services say employee, customer ..etc and register them all in start up of or main method in winforms which acts as a composition root i dont have a problem there but where should I put my container instance? it must be a place like main or it must be static where i can call it globally for resolves right? oh and another thing is there such as a Resolve factory? So i wont have to reference(using [namespace]) in every .cs file I call resolve?

Comment: Read this http://mookid.dk/oncode/archives/1854 you should get all your answers... plus the silverlight sample from the wiki as above. But yes, your container should live buried as a private variable within "Main"/StartUp Class and no one from outside should access it directly or through a ServiceLocator aka "the evil"(cit. Krzysztof Koźmic) :-)