# Structuremap Configuration with generics

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, structuremap

I have IRepository interface with which i want to use NHibernateRepository.

How do i configure it with structure map?

```
protected void ConfigureDependencies()
{
    ObjectFactory.Initialize(
        x =>
            {
                x.For<ILogger>().Use<Logger>();
                x.For<IRepository<T>>().Use<NHibernateRepository<T>>();
            }
        );
}
```

I m getting an error on T.

Comment: Try this: `x.For(typeof(IRepository<>)).Use(typeof(NHibernateRepository<>));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to map all closing types of `IRepository<>` to the corresponding closing type for `NHibernateRepository<>`, use:

```
x.For(typeof(IRepository<>)).Use(typeof(NHibernateRepository<>))
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is expecting a substitution for the generic parameter `T`:

```
x.For<IRepository<T>>().Use<NHibernateRepository<T>>();
```

That is, which type `T` will be stored in the repository? You've chosen the `NHibernateRepository` class as the implementation for `IRepository`, but haven't shown which internal class will be stored.

Alternatively, look at using non-generic IRepository, see here: [Generic repository - IRepository<T> or IRepository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853414/generic-repository-irepositoryt-or-irepository)

Comment: both interface and implementations are generic, so i can use any model class.

Comment: You can absolutely, but you can't use a generic type where you have it in your code because it is undeclared in the class. Perhaps use IRepository without generics, or try dynamic as suggested by the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps replace `<T>` with dynamic?

```
x.For<IRepository<dynamic>>().Use<NHibernateRepository<dynamic>>();
```

As for the second point, the Singleton / Service Locator pattern is a rather heated debate.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this article](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/12/18/advanced-structuremap-connecting-implementations-to-open-generic-types/). Basically, what you want to do is something like this:

```
public void ConfigureDependencies()
{
    ObjectFactory.Initialize(x => x.Scan(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.TheCallingAssembly();
        cfg.IncludeNamespaceContainingType<Logger>();
        cfg.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(NHibernateRepository<>));
    }));
}
```

Regarding the ApplicationContext static class: if you really have a cross-cutting concern, then I see nothing really wrong with it.